# Controller that works with several factories, has a couple different "states" and needs to update several $scope vars

Tags: javascript, angular.js

I have a controller that has gotten a little out of hand. This is my first AngularJS project and I am using it as a learning experience... but I feel like I am doing some things wrong.

This controller is used for resetting data on a weekly basis. There are "foos" of which 10 random foos are selected each week, "bars" which there is 1 random one each week, "bazs" which there is a sequence.

There are basically two states to this controller...

- first one would predict the 10 foos and then push a button to "start" the reset
- at this point the button would change to "finish reset" and the user would have to go to other pages to confirm 10 foos and 1 bar.
- then the user would come back to this page to finish the reset... when the user clicks to finish reset, the logic will confirm that 10 foos are confirmed and 1 bar is confirmed before saving this information into the archive.

What would be a better, less messy way of doing this? Some problems are... I've had to add code that refreshes the content of the page in several spots when I make changes to the database... and when one thing depends on another.. the nested callbacks seem to get pretty deep. Like...

```
get foos with status of 2
    validate that there are 5 of each 1 point and 2 point foos
    get bars with status 1
        validate that there is only 1
        create an archive
            change $scope vars to update the page
```

Here is the controller...

```
.controller('ResetController', function( $scope, fooFactory, siteMessageFactory, barFactory, bazFactory, archiveFactory ){

    $scope.startReset = function() {
        archiveFactory.getLast( function(a) {
            $scope.nextWeekStart = a.NextWeekStart.date.split(" ")[0];
            $scope.nextWeekEnd = a.NextWeekEnd.date.split(" ")[0];
            $scope.daysSinceReset = a.DaysSinceReset;
            if($scope.daysSinceReset < 6) {
                $scope.statusMessageActive = true;
                $scope.statusMessage = "There have only been "+ $scope.daysSinceReset +" days since the last reset, you cannot reset yet.";
            } else {
                siteMessageFactory.getWithCondition("name", "reset", function(sm) {
                    $scope.resetMessage = sm[0].SiteMessage;
                    if($scope.resetMessage.status === 1) {
                        $scope.statusMessageActive = true;
                        $scope.statusMessage = "The restart has already been started.";
                    } else {
                        $scope.resetMessage.status = 1;
                        siteMessageFactory.update($scope.resetMessage, function(data) {
                            console.log(data);
                        });
                        bazFactory.updateMany(true, {status: 0}, function(data) {
                            bazFactory.updateMany({ID : $scope.currentBaz.next_ID}, {status : 1}, function(data) {
                                $scope.currentBaz = $scope.nextBaz;
                            })
                        });
                        barFactory.updateMany(true, {status: 0}, function(data) {
                            $scope.bar = {name : "Unknown"};
                        });
                        fooFactory.updateMany(true, {status: 0}, function(data) {
                            $scope.confirmedFoos = [];
                            fooFactory.updateMany({predicted : 1},{status : 1, predicted : 0}, function(data) {
                                console.log(data);
                            });
                        });
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    };
    $scope.finishReset = function() {
        fooFactory.getWithCondition("status", 2, function(foos) {
            ones = 0;
            twos = 0;
            var message = "";
            var fooIds = [];
            for(o in foos) {
                fooIds.push(foos[o].Foo.ID);
                if(foos[o].Foo.points == 1) {
                    ones++;
                } else if (foos[o].Foo.points == 2) {
                    twos++;
                }
            }
            if(ones != 5) {
                message += " There should be 5 one point foos confirmed, you have "+ones+". ";
            }
            if(twos != 5) {
                message += " There should be 5 two point foos confirmed, you have "+twos+". ";
            }
            barFactory.getWithCondition("status", 1, function(bar) {
                if(bar.length != 1) {
                    message += " There needs to be an active bar to finish the reset. ";
                }
                if(message == "") {
                    archiveFactory.add(
                            {
                                Archive : 
                                {
                                    start_date : $scope.nextWeekStart,
                                    bar_ID : bar[0].Bar.ID
                                },
                                Foo : fooIds
                            }, function(data) {
                                $scope.statusMessageActive = true;
                                $scope.statusMessage = "Reset successfully saved."
                                $scope.resetComplete = true;
                            }
                    );
                    $scope.resetMessage.status = 0;
                    siteMessageFactory.update($scope.resetMessage, function(data) {
                        console.log(data);
                    });
                } else {
                    $scope.statusMessageActive = true;
                    $scope.statusMessage = message;
                }
            });
        });
    };
    siteMessageFactory.getWithCondition("name", "reset", function(o) {
        $scope.resetMessage = o[0].SiteMessage;
        if($scope.resetMessage.status) {
            fooFactory.getWithCondition("status", 2, function(foos) {
                $scope.confirmedFoos = foos;
            });
        } else {

        }
    });
    $scope.resetComplete = false;
    $scope.statusMessageActive = false;
    $scope.statusMessage = "";
    archiveFactory.getLast( function(o) {
        $scope.nextWeekStart = o.NextWeekStart.date.split(" ")[0];
        $scope.nextWeekEnd = o.NextWeekEnd.date.split(" ")[0];
        $scope.daysSinceReset = o.DaysSinceReset;
    });
    bazFactory.getWithCondition("status", 1, function(o) {
        $scope.currentBaz = o[0].Baz;
        bazFactory.find( $scope.currentBaz.next_ID, function(o) {
            $scope.nextBaz = o.Baz;
        });
    });
    barFactory.getWithCondition("status", 1, function(o) {
        if(o.length) {
            $scope.bar = o[0].Bar;
        } else {
            $scope.bar = {name: "Unknown"};
        }
    });
    fooFactory.getWithCondition("predicted", 1, function(foos) {
        $scope.predictedFoos = foos;
    });
    fooFactory.getWithCondition("predicted", 0, function(foos) {
        $scope.notPredictedFoos = foos;
    });
    $scope.changePredictionStatus = function(status, foo, fromArray) {
        fooFactory.update({"ID": foo.Foo.ID,"predicted": status}, function() {
            if(status == 1) {
                $scope.predictedFoos.push(foo);
            } else if (status == 0) {
                $scope.notPredictedFoos.push(foo);
            }
            for(var i = fromArray.length-1; i>= 0; i--) {
                if(fromArray[i].Foo.ID === foo.Foo.ID) {
                    fromArray.splice(i,1);
                }
            }
        })
    };
})
```

Comment: You should change the title to what the code actually does, not what you need review on.

Comment: @Chrillewoodz, better?

Comment: What about "Resetting data on a weekly basis using AngularJS"?

Comment: @Chrillewoodz, well I don't think that the fact that it is weekly really means a whole lot

Comment: No but that is the task that your code does, correct?

Comment: @Chrillewoodz, a user will manually do it once a week... but that isn't what the code does, the code just verifies that it's been atleast 6 days before a user tries to update... and then does all the updates needed.